# result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified (use strncmp instead) [-Wstring-compare] is the error i get please help me

Tags: c

please help me i am struggling with this it keeps giving me errors on errors btw LABEL 2 leads to the main part

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    char d[10],e[10];

    Label:

    printf("Username of the agent: ");

    scanf("%s",d);

    printf("Password: ");

    scanf("%s",e);


    if(d=="Vayush" && e=="Vasireddy")
        { goto Label2;}
    else
        printf("wrong username and password\n");
    goto Label;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(d=="Vayush" && e=="Vasireddy")
```

is comparing pointers to string literals, thats wrong because you want to compare contents and not addresses. The compiler is telling you to use the standard function `strncmp` instead of `==`, in this case `strcmp` can do the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // strcmp

int main(void) // Use a valid signature
{
    // Use meaningful names for your vars
    char usr[10];
    char pwd[10];

    // Do not use goto, loop until you get valid values
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Username of the agent: ");
        // scanf return the number of input items successfully matched or EOF
        int n = scanf("%9s", usr); // %9s in order to avoid buffer overflows
        if (n == EOF) { break; }
        if (n == 1)
        {
            printf("Password: ");
            n = scanf("%9s", pwd);
            if (n == EOF) { break; }
            if ((n == 1) &&
                (strcmp(usr, "Vayush") == 0) &&
                (strcmp(pwd, "Vasireddy") == 0))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("wrong username and password\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: oh thank you so much for those helpful comments as well

you are the best!